# Flutter Web cloud_firestore package: Versions newer than 0.12.11 produces just a blank web page

Tags: flutter, web, google-cloud-firestore

When I run the command: flutter build web => I get a blank web page. If I use cloud_firestore::0.12.11 OR older, all runs perfectly well.

Steps to reproduce the behavior:

- flutter doctor. No issues found.
- flutter run -d chrome. The app runs OK on the local browser.
- flutter build web. The app runs and shows a blank page.
- In pubspec.yaml: remove the dependency cloud_firestore: The app runs OK.
- In pubspec.yaml: add the dependency cloud_firestore:0.12.11 (older version), The app runs OK.

Expected behavior

- I need to use cloud_firestore: 0.14.0+2 so I can use the data type FirebaseFirestore.

Answer (score 0):

Are you also using other firebase packages? I have found there are issues with `firebase_auth` - including a black screen.

Make sure you following the Migration Guide: https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/migration/#plugin-changes

Comment: Even if I don't use any other dependencies whatsoever, the webpahe doesn't  get rendered if I use cloud_firestore newer than 0.12.11

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with a bug in the library  itself.

Comment: I'm having the same exact issue, can you tell how you resolved it?